# webpack-dev-server - Is possible to use an `index.html` and `main.js` from outside the root?

Tags: webpack, gulp, webpack-dev-server

#### Context

I am using gulp to build my code and using Webpack just for webpack-dev-server and the hot-reload feature. Hot reload works as expected, but, I need to serve `index.html` and `main.js` entry points from a separate folder in my root directory apart from the ones that gulp uses to build my code.

#### Question

**webpack-dev-server**, as far as I have read from the docs, can only be given one directory to serve which should contain all the file structure including the `index.html` and `main.js`.

My question is that is there a way to tell **Webpack** to use the directory that `webpack.config.js` is in, ***but***, excluding `index.html` and `main.js`, ***and instead***, go to another folder and use those `index.html` and `main.js` while hot reloading.

So, basically I want this to work:

```
- src/
 -- assets/
 -- components/
 -- dev/
  --- main.jsx
  --- index.html
 -- main.jsx
 -- index.html
- webpack.config.js
- gulpfile.js
```

1. When I run `gulp build` it uses the above directory excluding `dev/`.
2. When I spin **webpack-dev-server** it uses the `dev/` for entry points and omits `index.html` and `main.js` in `src/`.

**Note:** I know I can't make it happen from gulp file the other way, however, I don't want to change how it works, I need it intact)

#### Why, though?

Because this is a huge project written in React and compiles the code using Gulp to some certain folders and I don't wanna change any of those codes since many others relying on those. Originally this project wasn't using hot-reload and now I am introducing **Webpack** just for the dev server and hot reload. The problem was because Gulp compiles this code into a completely separate directory, all the paths are different in the `index.html` and I need and `index.html` that shows the right paths for **webpack-dev-server**.

And about `main.js`, I need to place a line where I import the CSS to show the CSS files to **webpack-dev-server** but that messes up the building process of Gulp script.